# Jquery not working

Tags: php, jquery

For some reason, my jQuery isn't working properly, and I can't spot the mistake, although I may have some idea. Below is some of the code from group2.php, its for a chat application:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="menu">
        <p class="welcome">Welcome, <b><?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?></b></p>
        <p class="logout"><a id="exit" href="?logout=1">Exit Group</a></p>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>  

   if(isset($_GET['logout'])){  
     $fp = fopen("log.html", 'w');
     fwrite($fp, "");
     fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'><i>User " . $_SESSION['name'] . " has left the chat session.</i><br></div>");
     fclose($fp);       
     session_destroy();
     header("Location: main.php"); //Redirect the user        
     }



?>
</div>
```

**While below is jQuery, which is also in group2.php, where I am trying to see if the user clicked logout, then we should direct to main.php?logout=true**

```
//If user wants to end session
    $("#exit").click(function(){
      var exit = confirm("Are you sure you want to end the session?");
      if(exit==true){ window.location = 'main.php?logout=true';
      }
    });
```

While I am able to execute the code within `if(isset($_GET['logout']))`, and ask the user whether they would like to leave the room, I am unable to direct the user to `main.php?logout=true` after they click 'ok' to the question 'Want to end session?'. Instead, the user is being directed to `?logout=1`. Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the *default* action in this case, which is to go to the `href` in the `<a>`.  You can do that with [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or `return false`, like this:

```
$("#exit").click(function(e) {
   if(confirm("Are you sure you want to end the session?")) {
     window.location = 'main.php?logout=true';
   }
   e.preventDefault();
   //or: return false;
});
```

Or, if you're never going to use it, just remove the `href` url, like this:

```
<a id="exit" href="#">Exit Group</a>
```

Comment: Nick, after following your steps I am being directed to main.php?logout=true, as I had wished but now my code for if(isset($_GET['logout'])) won't execute. i.e. the file won't truncate. When I used your latter advice, the same thing happened. Any suggestions?

Comment: @newbie-25 - Is `main.php` the page you posted? I thought from the question it's `group2.php`, what does `main.php` look like?

Comment: Right, both of the above codes come from group2.php, where the chat application is located. But when the user clicks 'Exit Group', I want him/her to be directed to main.php or main.php?logout=true. Main.php is where OTHER chat rooms are located, incase the user wants to enter other rooms. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

Because `true` is just a constant for 1

Also your `header()` call in the PHP to redirect won't work because you've output HTML already.

Answer (score 1):

First lets start with your javascript:

Personally I would cause it to confirm and then prevent the default if they click the cancel button like this.

```
$("#exit").click(function(e) {
   if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to end the session?")) {
     e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

This would cause the link not to be followed if they click cancel but to follow the link if not. The reason I would do it this way is because if they have javascript turned off they won't get the confirmation dialog but the logout will still work as intended.

Next your PHP/HTML:

if you are using the exact code you posted then you missed a

```
<?php
 if(isset($_GET['logout'])){    

    $fp = fopen("log.html", 'w');
    fwrite($fp, "");
    fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'><i>User " . $_SESSION['name'] . " has left the chat session.</i><br></div>");
    fclose($fp); 

    session_destroy();
    header("Location: main.php"); //Redirect the user
    exit;

 }
?>
```

If your header functions are not executed before ANY output, even a single blank space it, will cause an error. The exception to this is if output buffering is turned on in your php.ini file. The problem with that is if you want to put the a diff server that doesn't have this turned on it will err unexpectedly. Alternatively you could use ob_start() and ob_end_flush() at the beginning of ever script but truly output buffering is a crutch that shouldn't be relied on when its just as easy to structure your code so that you don't need it.

Other things I noticed is that you are using a text file. I would definitely consider a database. If you do insist on text file, you might want to change the 'w' in your fopen to an 'a' so you are appending the file instead of writing. The w option will truncate the file each time you run this script so you will start with an empty file then write your line and the next time the script is executed you will get an empty file.

Hope this helps

-kel

Comment: @ Kel - Thank you for your former part. Everything as of now is working fine for the chat application, except I was unable to keep the user on the chat page just in case if they had clicked 'cancel' just like you mentioned. But, when I applied your code, the isset($_GET['logout'] code would NOT work. I.e. the file won't truncate (That is exactly what I want it to do because when a user leaves a chat session, I want their old messages to be deleted on THEIR screen at least. Therefore, preventDefault seems to make the javascript work but it also causes my other code to not execute. Hmm.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I should have specified that your url in the href needs to contain the link with the parameters..

<a href="main.php?logout=true">Logout</a>

then when they click ok, the default will not be prevented and their browser will follow the link and log out.